# Excel Hyperlink function not working anymore: "cannot open specified file"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I had a hyperlink function the worked perfectly, but once excel updated, its stopped working.
It would use two inputs to search for a cell on another worksheet on the same workbook then offset -1. It worked perfectly, but excel updated their formula language, and now, when ever I try to click on my formula the error "cannot open specified file" pops up. With this new update, I can't figure out how to change my function so it works again. I've copied and pasted the function below. Any help would be appreciated.

`=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDEX(Table8[F],MATCH(1,('Sheet2 (2)'!J7=Table8[F])*('Sheet2 (2)'!G3=Table8[P]),0)),-1,0)),)`

I've tried adding quotation marks and pound symbols (example below) and it returns with "N/A" value. I've tried removing Add-ins, repairing microsoft office programs, turning off automatic updates for links. Nothing works.

`=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDEX("#Sheet1!Table8[D]",MATCH(1,('Sheet2 (2)'!J6="#sheet1!Table8[D]")*('Sheet2 (2)'!G3="#sheet1!Table8[P]"),0)),-1,0)),)`

Comment: Not sure if this will help you out or not, but I got screwed over with excel hyperlink FUNCTION and the hyperlink you can add by right clicking on a cell and selecting it from the menu.  My hyperlink from the FUNCTION displayed perfectly and updated when things changed.  However when I clicked on the cell it was activating the MENU hyperlink instead.  It was a tedious process but at the time my only solution was to right click on the cell and select remove hyperlink which removed the MENYU hyperlink.  Then the one from the formula started working.

Comment: no, I don't use the hyperlink that you get from right clicking on the cell and manually creating a hyperlink. I think there may be something wrong with my excel settings or something. I just found a older version of my work book and the hyperlink function works fine. But even if i make a new workbook, the hyperlink function will only work when written like =HYPERLINK("#L5")